# How to pass a value from asp.net datalist to javascript textbox?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I already have a dataList:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dlIndex" runat="server" Width="61%" Height="83px">     
        <ItemTemplate>
               <td style="text-align: center; padding-right: 0px; width: 50px;"> 
                   <asp:Label ID="Adress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("artikli_na_skladistu.skladista.Adresa")%>'></asp:Label> 
               </td>                
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Now, I want to pass the value of the Label to a javascript textbox let's say ...

```
<input type="text" id="fname" value="">

document.getElementById("fname").value = getVal();

function getVal() {
      ???
}
```

So when I run the web site, I wanna see the value of the datalist Label inside the textbox javascript  ...
How do I do that ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You haven't thought out your solution well enough. If you only have one item, why are you using a DataList? You should directly bind in the markup using `<%=MyObject.artikli_na_skladistu.skladista.Adresa%>`. If you have more than one item in your DataList, how are you going to figure out which one to show?

Comment: There is more, but I want this one especially.  var foo = document.getElementById("<%= dlIndex.artikli_na_skladistu.skladista.Adresa %>"); doesn't seems to work, it doesn't recognize anything after "dlIndex".

Comment: And var foo = document.getElementById("<%= dlIndex.ClientID %>"); gives me an "undefined"

Comment: You have a server-side object (a class or something) that has data, and you are binding a collection of them to a control that acts like a repeater for many instances of the object. You're saying you only need one of those objects, though. Either find a way to create a unique ID or selector for the one label you want so you can select it with Javascript, or stop using the DataList entirely and get the one instance of the data you need on the server side and expose it in the markup. You can just do document.getElementById("fname").value = <% myInstance.artikli_na_skladistu.skladista.Adresa %>

Comment: Or better yet, don't even set it with javascript, <input type="text" id="fname" value="<%=myInstance.artikli_na_skladistu.skladista.Adresa%>">. You will need to filter bad characters if you do it this way though

Comment: Well as I said it before, It doesn't recognize anything after "dlIndex". Only dlIndex.ClientID is recognized and throws me a "undefined". btw I like the <input type="text" id="fname" value="<%=myInstance.artikli_na_skladistu.skladista.Adresa%>"> answer ... it's a shame ...

Comment: dlIndex is the list itself. You can't get data by selecting the list. The data you want is in an object, that is inside a collection, that is bound to the data source of the list. Either dig down into the collection on the server side and pull out the data you need and make it a field on your page, or use ClientIdMode on a control inside your template to expose a way to select the one element you want in your list.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution ... it's very, very ugly, but it works (for me)::

So, in the datalist ... the Label(s) was an asp.net Label(s) ... I change it javascript Label, like so:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlIndex" runat="server" Width="61%" Height="83px">     
        <ItemTemplate>
            <label id="Adresa"><%# Eval("artikli_na_skladistu.skladista.Adresa") %></label>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and then, I just had to call it in javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
      var url = "/Something.aspx?val=" + document.getElementById("Adresa").textContent;
</script>
```

I really am a newbie in javascript ... so this really works for me ... 
Thanks to everyone who replied :D